# CSS footer column spacing

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I need some assistance with my code I am looking to creating a footer with four equal columns, right now the fourth column in spaced too far to the right, any assistance you can provide is appreciated.

```css
#footer {
  background: #E5E0DD;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 860px;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 26px 0 0;
  width: 960px;
}

#footer div div {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 240px;
}

#footer div div h3 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#footer div div ul,
#footer div div ul li {
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer div div ul li {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #06C;
}

#footer div p {
  color: #c1c1c1;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: left;
  padding: 0 0 2px 0;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3>Policies & Directives</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-4">
       <a href="https://.net/Policies/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?"></a></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>In the know...</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-4">
  <!-- FAQs- Select and move from comments based on appropriate   
   page-->
    <a href="#"
      </span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- Centers -->
      <h3>Centers</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-4">
 
  <a href= "https://net.Home.aspx">FAQs</a><br/>
  <!-- Glossary -->                                                  
  </span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- About -->
      <h3>About</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-4">
  <a href="https://netMission Statement.aspx">Mission Statement</a><br>
 <a href="About.aspx?LA=#">Overview</a><br>
        <a href= "https://net%20Chart%20and%20Phone%">Organizational</a>     
 </span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was unnecessary and difficult for no reason. I need help with my code. I am looking for columns equally spaced.

Comment: Please put it in a CodePen or similar for us. I just pasted your code into CodePen and it doesn't have four columns. I'm happy to help, but please get it into a form that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "This was unnecessary and difficult for no reason. I need help with my code." If you think it was difficult for you, how about the time people are spending to help you. Welcome to stack overflow. Read about how to write great questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I agree that posting your code snippet was a bit of a waste, but mostly because it's too specific. A simplified jsFiddle like some of us provided would have been well worth your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you the basic building blocks and the following methods you can go about achieving this:

1. **Float Method**
2. **Inline-Block Method**
3. **Flex Method**

```css
.footer-col {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float .footer-col {
    float: left;
}

footer#footer {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.inline-block .footer-col {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 24.5%;
}

#footer.flex {
    display: flex;
}

h3 {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

h3:first-of-type {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Float Method</h3>
<footer id="footer" class="float">
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
</footer>

<h3>Inline-Block Method</h3>
<footer id="footer" class="inline-block">
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
</footer>

<h3>Flex Method</h3>
<footer id="footer" class="flex">
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
  <div class="footer-col"></div>
</footer>
```

The rest is up to you!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 4 ways to create an element with children that are evenly divided. Inline-block, tables, floats, and flex-box.

Inline-block has a funny space to account for between them... so, 25% will not work as you expect. Tables are for data(in my opinion). Floats are great, but they take themselves our of the document flow in a way you need to understand well. [Flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is probably the most versitile, but you need to be aware of the browser prefixes or use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). Here is an example of both floats and flex-box.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fbatsw02/

### Markup

```
<footer class="site-footer floats">
<div class="inner-w">

  <ul class="module-list">

    <li class="module">one</li>
    <li class="module">two</li>
    <li class="module">three</li>
    <li class="module">four</li>

  </ul>

</div>
</footer>



<footer class="site-footer flex-box">
<div class="inner-w">

  <ul class="module-list">

    <li class="module">one</li>
    <li class="module">two</li>
    <li class="module">three</li>
    <li class="module">four</li>

  </ul>

</div>
</footer>
```

### Styles

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-footer .inner-w {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.module-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.module {
  padding: 1rem;
}


/* with floats */
.site-footer.floats {
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden; /* fixes how the inner float collapses this element */
}

.site-footer.floats .module {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}


/* with flexbox */
.site-footer.flex-box {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.site-footer.flex-box .module-list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.site-footer.flex-box .module {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```